# Range error after running flutter run post null safety migration

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

The relevant error-causing widget was:
MaterialApp MaterialApp:file:///C:/ff/ffflutter/lib/main.dart:62:14

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
#1      _QuizPageState.initState (package:fragrancefinder/pages/QuizPage.dart:108:50)

main.dart

here is the relevant code

```
child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: MainPage(
            country: '',
            local: '',
          )),
    ));
```

QuizPage.dart

```
  if (stageOneQuestions[0].images.length <= 1) {
      preferenceAnswer = getAnswerFromImagePath(
          stageOneQuestions[0].images[0]['imagePath'].toString());.........
```